# Error while installing PySWIP for use of Prolog in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to follow the installation guide for [PySWIP](https://code.google.com/p/pyswip/wiki/INSTALL) in Windows, which first asks to install a *32 bit* version of [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable) first and include its bin in PATH, which I did. Then I installed the 64 bit version of PySWIP since my Python-2.7 is 64 bit Anaconda version. But it doesn't work (see error below).

As suggested by some elsewhere, I also made of copy of libswipl.dll (in C:\Program Files (x86)\pl\bin ) as libpl.dll and of swipl.ico  (in C:\Program Files (x86)\pl ) as pl.ico but no luck.

The error that I am getting (in Spyder and EclipsePyDev IDEs using Anaconda interpreter) when I enter the first line below is:

```
>>> from pyswip import Prolog
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyswip\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
        from pyswip.prolog import Prolog
      File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyswip\prolog.py", line 29, in <module>
        from pyswip.core import *
      File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyswip\core.py", line 360, in <module>
        _lib = CDLL(_path)
      File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How to fix this?

Background: I am working through the first order logic programming of natural language semantics of [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html#ex-northprop), and I thought it would be nice to have a logic program that can do constraint programming (specifically, solve for equality logical constraints)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer - it was that I should have installed a 64 bit (instead of 32 bit) version of SWI-Prolog for it to work with 64 bit PySWIP and Python (even though the installation guide at PySWIP specifically mentioned 32 bit SWI-Prolog). Its working now.

PS: I didn't find the need to rename libswipl.dll or swipl.ico

Comment: In my case it was just the opposite. My python installation was 32 bit. Anyway thank you.